# how to get the text inside the href? (web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape and filter all the links that I want from a website and put them in the list called URLs, [image: this is the picture of it.]
Now I want to include all the strings in the href to the website.

```
website = 'https://bj.ke.com/ershoufang/chaoyang/'
```

So, for example, I want it to loops like these

https://bj.ke.com/ershoufang/chaoyang/ershoufang/andingmen/

for all the `href` in my list

Comment: What have you tried so far? Copy some of your code here so others can take a look and help.

Comment: Please do not post images as code. Instead, [edit] your question with the code you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

You can add `https://bj.ke.com` in all element  of list by doing this:

```
CompleteLinks=list(map(lambda x:"https://bj.ke.com"+x["href"],urls))
```

Comment: @Betty if any queries ask in comment! And if this solves your problem mark this as accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `href` using `tag-name[href]` and concatenate the base URL with it. For example:

```
print(
    ["https://bj.ke.com/ershoufang/chaoyang" + tag["href"] for tag in urls]
)
```

Comment: Usually use `"{}".format(pattern)` to avoid interruption (`unsupported operand type`) in case if the data is int.